# iOS access recent emails

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, email

I know this is likely to be answered "sorry buddy", but is there a way i can access my recently sent emails from another iOS app?  I really don't need the contents of the emails just the addresses.  Basically if you haven't stored the contact information in your address book, I still want to be able to pull those addresses.

For example in the email app, when you compose a new email, as you start typing in an email address it will try to autofill with recently sent/received email addresses.  I'm trying to mimic this behavior.

Point me in the right direction if there is already a stack overflow question about this.

Comment: sorry buddy :D ... couldnt resist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not API that will allow this.

Apps can't acces other apps data since they are sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Given the quick answers I received confirming my suspicion that this can't be done, I'm thinking I will just provide a way people can set up email accounts the way the built-in mail app does it.  By that I mean I will allow people to select from the major web-based mail providers like gmail, yahoo mail, .. then also allow them to create a mail account with their mail server (address, username, password, port, etc.)

It's kind of overkill since I just want their recently used email addresses, and will scare off people who don't want to give access to their personal mail, but if its all i can do then so be it.

Comment: You could access the phones contacts, though.

Comment: Like @Emil pointed out, you should really have a look at the address book API. [Address Book Framework Reference for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212) will tell you all you need to know and will be far less work then writing your own mail client connection.

Comment: appreciate the responses, the point is that i'm trying to get access to email addresses that aren't in the user's address book. personally, i manage a lot of my business contacts via my inbox and don't actually add to my AddressBook.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I guess you aren't programming for a jailbroken version of iOS either, but if you were, there are ways to get access to it.